# What's the difference between `stack install NAME` and `NAME` in the build-depends of project.cabal file?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

What is the difference between adding `package_name` under the `build-depends:` section in a project's `.cabal file`, versus doing `stack install package_name` within that project's directory?

Comment: You may want to modify your question title, since "`import NAME` in project.cabal file" isn't very clear. Import statements belong in Haskell files, not .cabal files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stack install` will just install the package to the appropriate place (the current snapshot database for libraries in Stackage, the sandbox in `./.stack-work` for other libraries, `~/.local/bin` or your system's equivalent thereof for executables). Adding a library to `build-depends` specifies it as a dependency of your project, and leads to the library being installed next time you do a `stack build`. If you are actually using the library in your project you must add it to `build-depends`, otherwise you won't be able to build the project (or even play with the library using `stack ghci`).

N.B.: As of stack-0.1.3.1, `stack install NAME` is just a synonym for `stack build --copy-bins NAME`. The `--copy-bins` option tells stack to copy any executables to `~/.local/bin`. If your package is just a library with no executables, `stack install NAME` is the same as `stack build NAME`.

Comment: Does that also pick the newest resolver each time, or does it read the closest stack.yaml, or does it use ~/.stack/config.yaml even if I'm in ~/src/my-stack-project?

Comment: Also, can I put "dependencies" into the global config for `~` s.t. on a new computer I can just copy over my stack config file and `stack build` to get stuff like hindent, stylish-haskell and hlint?