# Hidden package binary-0.7.5.0?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I get this error:

```
Could not find module â€˜Data.Binaryâ€™
It is a member of the hidden package â€˜binary-0.7.5.0@binar_IvYoLp9H6Xy3zEH13MmZwdâ€™.
```

as I import `Data.Binary` in my stack project with GHCi version 7.10.2.

Strange things are that this does not appear if I execute the GHCi through `stack exec ghci`, and that I cannot install newer versions of `binary` package through stack, which looks:

```
D:\p>stack install binary
Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC
NOTE: the install command is functionally equivalent to 'build --copy-bins'

D:\p>stack install binary-0.7.6.1
Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC
NOTE: the install command is functionally equivalent to 'build --copy-bins'
Error parsing targets: Specified target version 0.7.6.1 for package binary does not match snapshot version 0.7.5.0

D:\p>stack install binary-0.7.5.0
Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC
NOTE: the install command is functionally equivalent to 'build --copy-bins'
```

How would you get around this problem?

Comment: See also: [What's the difference between `stack install NAME` and `NAME` in the build-depends of project.cabal file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32303377/2751851)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `binary` dependency to your `cabal` file.

```
build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                   , binary >= 0.7.5
```

When you use `stack install` you are installing certain library or executable but not as dependency (e.g. is a utility like `yesod` or some library you are using only inside `ghci` ...).

Comment: An additional remark: Adding dependencies to the .cabal file is actually the primary way of installing libraries with stack. Once a dependency is added, it will be installed automatically the first time it is needed (e.g. when you run `stack build`).

Comment: Thank you for the solution! But why is the package hidden inside of any stack packages while it's not outside?

Comment: @RyoichiroOka stack/cabal found that package (they are suggesting one version) but is hidden for your project (since you are not including it in it); inclusion is not automatic (usual behavior in many languages)

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you for your answer :)