# Could not find module ‘Test.HUnit’

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a fresh installation of stack and ghci:

```
$ stack --version
```

> ```
> Version 1.6.3, Git revision b27e629b8c4ce369e3b8273f04db193b060000db (5454 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
> ```

```
$ ghci --version
```

> ```
> The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.1
> ```

I make a new project:

```
$ stack new so-mve
```

> ```
> Downloading template "new-template" to create project "so-mve" in so-mve/ 
> ... blah blah blah ...
> Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
> Using cabal packages:
> - so-mve/
> Selecting the best among 12 snapshots...
> * Matches lts-10.3
> Selected resolver: lts-10.3
> Initialising configuration using resolver: lts-10.3
> Total number of user packages considered: 1
> Writing configuration to file: so-mve/stack.yaml
> All done.
> ```

Looks pretty good:

```
$ tree so-mve
```

> ```
> so-mve
> ├── ChangeLog.md
> ├── LICENSE
> ├── README.md
> ├── Setup.hs
> ├── app
> │   └── Main.hs
> ├── package.yaml
> ├── so-mve.cabal
> ├── src
> │   └── Lib.hs
> ├── stack.yaml
> └── test
>     └── Spec.hs
> ```

It builds and runs:

```
$ cd so-mve
$ stack build
```

> ```
> so-mve-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
> Preprocessing library for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Building library for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Preprocessing executable 'so-mve-exe' for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Building executable 'so-mve-exe' for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> so-mve-0.1.0.0: copy/register
> Installing library in /...blah-blah.../so-mve/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-10.3/8.2.2/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.2.2/so-mve-0.1.0.0-5kG2WnHWwo99IiYYGoxrcC
> Installing executable so-mve-exe in /...blah-blah.../so-mve/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-10.3/8.2.2/bin
> Registering library for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> ```

```
$ stack exec so-mve-exe
```

> ```
> someFunc
> ```

Tests run:

```
$ stack test
```

> ```
> blah blah blah
> [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( test/Spec.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/so-mve-test/so-mve-test-tmp/Main.o )
> ...blah-blah-blah...
> Progress: 1/2Test suite not yet implemented
> so-mve-0.1.0.0: Test suite so-mve-test passed
> Completed 2 action(s).
> ```

I triple check that `HUnit` is installed

```
$ stack install HUnit
```

> ```
> Populated index cache.
> ```

I add one line to `test/Spec.hs`

```
$ cat test/Spec.hs
```

> ```
> import Test.HUnit
> main :: IO ()
> main = putStrLn "Test suite not yet implemented"
> ```

Doesn't work:

```
$ stack test
```

> ```
> so-mve-0.1.0.0: unregistering (components added: test:so-mve-test)
> so-mve-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe + test)
> Preprocessing library for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Building library for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Preprocessing executable 'so-mve-exe' for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Building executable 'so-mve-exe' for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Preprocessing test suite 'so-mve-test' for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> Building test suite 'so-mve-test' for so-mve-0.1.0.0..
> [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( test/Spec.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/so-mve-test/so-mve-test-tmp/Main.o )
> ```

```
/...blah-blah.../so-mve/test/Spec.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Test.HUnit’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |          
1 | import Test.HUnit
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Progress: 1/2
--  While building custom Setup.hs for package so-mve-0.1.0.0 using:
      /Users/XXXXXXXX/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build lib:so-mve exe:so-mve-exe test:so-mve-test --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I don't have trouble importing other libraries, like `Text.Read` and `Text.Printf`. 
I googled around a bunch, but didn't find an answer. Any ideas for me?

Comment: You've tagged this `cabal`, should it be tagged `stack`? And have you added `HUnit` to your test project's dependencies in `package.yaml`?

Comment: What does your `.cabal` file look like? You need to specify the `HUnit` dependency in the part of the cabal file that specifies the test build.

Comment: @hnefatl The tag `stack` would have to be something new because SO suggests that it means stack-the-data-structure, also suggesting a bunch of things having to do with stack-as-in-stackoverflow. I settled on `cabal` as a fallback.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Sorry, I meant `haskell-stack`.

Comment: @hnetfatl oh, cool! For the next one, i’ll know how to tag it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to add `HUnit` to the dependencies for your test project. When using `stack`, you should edit the `package.yaml` file to specify dependencies. In particular, your test configuration should look something like:

```
tests:
  so-mve-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - ...
    dependencies:
    - HUnit
```

This is documented in the latest [Stack Guide](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md), under the section [Adding Dependencies](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#adding-dependencies).

Comment: Both answers are spot on. I'm giving you the check-mark for the added reference to the stack documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You installed `HUnit` globally with `stack`, but that doesn't mean it is [specified for your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303377/whats-the-difference-between-stack-install-name-and-name-in-the-build-depen).

Your `cabal` file for the project needs to specify a dependency on `HUnit`:

```
--so-mve.cabal
...
test-suite so-mve 
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , HUnit
  ...
```

`Text.Read` and `Text.Printf` are both included in [`base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base), so you don't need to specify an additional dependency.

---

As pointed out in the comments, since you're using a `package.yaml` (as opposed to a `stack.yaml`) configuration with the newer version of `stack`, you'll need to specify the dependency there instead of the `.cabal` file:

```
tests:
  so-mve-test:
    main: Spec.hs
    source-dirs: test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    dependencies:
    - HUnit
```

Comment: From the actual content of the OP's post, it's clear they're using `stack` rather than `cabal`.

Comment: @hnefatl `stack` uses a `.cabal` file still.

Comment: @hnefatl And in fact, stack new creates that file for you, as you can see in OP's output of `tree`

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be edited - when using `stack`, the `package.yaml` file is the primary configuration file, while the `.cabal` file is frequently overwritten by `stack`.

Comment: Ah I forgot about that change with recent versions of stack, I'm still using `stack.yaml` files.